# INSTALL_FAILED_DUPLICATE_PERMISSION: Package

Tags: installation, apk, android-permissions

I wanted to install the apk of a game that I had a long time ago but I get an error for duplicate permission, I guess it stayed even after deleting the game and now it won't let me install a newer version

I tried to search the entire cell phone for the permission but couldn't find it.